# How to get row count with same field value as from row with provided id?

Tags: android, sql

Not sure that title clears my question. What i need is:
TABLE: id, year
Example data:

```
+--+----+
|id|year|
+--+----+
|1 |1990|
+--+----+
|2 |1990|
+--+----+
|3 |1990|
+--+----+
|4 |1992|
+--+----+
|5 |1992|
+--+----+
```

On input i receive an ID. For id 1 result must be 3 (cause 3 rows shares the same year as row with id 1). Any way to avoid subquery?
(Also code snippet for android would be fine too :), Thanks.

Comment: that's usually the work for count(*) and group by. I am not sure if android supports it and how it does work with cursor

Comment: well, sql query would be fine too

Comment: then try: select year, count (*) from yourtable group by year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.year, count(*) 
FROM TEMP t1 INNER JOIN TEMP t2 ON t1.year=t2.year
GROUP BY t1.year, t2.id
```

Look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/38b05/4

Answer (score 0):

First extract distinct year name using

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT year FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
```

Result of this query will be

```
1990
1992
```

After getting this you can use to get all the row for selected year

```
String query = "Select * from "+TABLE_NAME+ " where year = '"+year
```

You can store this in an ArrayList() and able get count by calling size() method

Answer (score 0):

in extension to @Johnny_H you can try to run the following query:

```
SELECT year, count (*)
FROM youttable
GROUP BY year
```

still you have to check if `GROUP BY` is available on Android